# How to create a global settings file in react css modules

Tags: reactjs, react-css-modules

I want to have a file just to store the colors and some other settings that I am going to use in my css styles. Because I don't want to specify the same color in different files multiple times. How can I achieve that with css modules?

For example:
setting.css

```
$primary-color: #785372;
$secondary-corlor: #22b390;
```

Button/styles.css

```
.button {
  background: $primary-color;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your samples that looks like Sass (which can be used in conjunction with CSS modules). If so then just import the partial containing the variables.

```
@import 'path/to/variables.scss';
```

If there's no Sass involved then [postcss-modules-values](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules-values) is what your looking for:

`variables.css`

```
@value primary: #785372;
@value secondary: #22b390;
```

`styles.css`

```
@value primary, secondary from './path/to/variables.css';

.button {
  background: primary;
  display: flex;
}
```

EDIT:
Actually there's even more options, still through PostCSS plugins. [postcss-simple-vars](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-simple-vars) or [postcss-custom-properties](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-custom-properties), the later having the clear advantage to stay close to the CSS specification.
They all share the same requirement though, importing the configuration file in a way or another.

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.

Comment: import it into your `App.scss` file (i bet you have that one)

Comment: CSS modules are processed per file, and not from a root file importing all the partials like Sass does. So this won't work. The partial with variables needs to be imported in each module file (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with using *CSS Custom Properties* ([here's a tutorial I've found](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/css/css-variables-for-react-devs/)).

In your `settings.css` file, do (the `:root':

```
:root {
    --primary-color: #785372;
    --secondary-corlor: #22b390;
}
```

Then, you can use those constants in the same, or a different file

```
.container {
    color: var(--primary-color);
}
```

If you're using them in a different file, be sure to import both stylesheets, for example:

```
import './Button/styles.css'
import './settings.css'
```

Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581552/10787371), you can do this in html as well, by linking the two stylesheets:

```
<link href="settings.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="Button/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```